# How to consolidate columns based on dates with SQL

Tags: mysql

If I have the following SQL `my_table`:

```
 ╔══════╦═════════════════════╦═══════════╦═══════════════╗
 ║  id  ║    date_recorded    ║ new_entry ║ price_updated ║
 ╠══════╬═════════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════════╣
 ║ ...  ║ ...                 ║    ...    ║      ...      ║
 ║ 120  ║ 2020-02-13 18:53:49 ║    15     ║      13       ║
 ║ 121  ║ 2020-02-14 00:52:58 ║     5     ║       2       ║
 ║ 122  ║ 2020-02-14 06:53:38 ║     1     ║       4       ║
 ║ 123  ║ 2020-02-14 12:54:21 ║     5     ║       1       ║
 ║ 124  ║ 2020-02-14 18:54:50 ║     9     ║       9       ║
 ║ 125  ║ 2020-02-15 00:54:45 ║     7     ║      11       ║
 ║ ...  ║ ...                 ║    ...    ║      ...      ║
 ╚══════╩═════════════════════╩═══════════╩═══════════════╝
```

**Question:**

How would I write an SQL Query to query all the dates in `my_table` so the output is just the date and the `new_entry` & `price_updated` columns are consolidated into one row for all dates in the `date_recorded` column:

```
 ╔═════════════════╦═══════════╦═══════════════╗
 ║  date_recorded  ║ new_entry ║ price_updated ║
 ╠═════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════════╣
 ║ ...             ║    ...    ║      ...      ║
 ║ 2020-02-13      ║    15     ║      13       ║
 ║ 2020-02-14      ║    20  #  ║      16 *     ║  #20 = 5 + 1 + 5 + 9  |  *16 = 2 + 4 + 9 + 1
 ║ 2020-02-15      ║     7     ║      11       ║ 
 ║ ...             ║    ...    ║      ...      ║
 ╚═════════════════╩═══════════╩═══════════════╝
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a `GROUP BY` expression, grouping on the `DATE` part of `date_recorded` and `SUM`ming the `new_entry` and `price_updated` values:

```
SELECT DATE(date_recorded) AS date_recorded,
       SUM(new_entry) AS new_entry,
       SUM(price_updated) AS price_updated
FROM my_table
GROUP BY DATE(date_recorded)
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/daf4a3/2)